# android silk library imports with errors

Tags: android, import, adt

I am trying to import the silk library so I can use [card ui](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI). (The card ui has a link to the silk library. I would post a link directly to it, but the site won't let me) the library imports, but I get the following errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ClickableToast.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views  line 36 Java Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingStart' in package 'android'   dialog_listitem_checkbox.xml    /Silk-master/res/layout line 8  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ClickableToast.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views  line 37 Java Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingEnd' in package 'android' dialog_listitem_checkbox.xml    /Silk-master/res/layout line 8  Android AAPT Problem
The import com.afollestad.silk.R cannot be resolved ClickableToast.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views  line 11 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDatePicker.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views/time line 153    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ClickableToast.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views  line 79 Java Problem
The import com.afollestad.silk.R cannot be resolved SilkListFragment.java   /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/fragments/list line 14 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDatePicker.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views/time line 91 Java Problem
The import com.afollestad.silk.R cannot be resolved SilkDatePicker.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/views/time line 11 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 379    Java Problem
The import com.afollestad.silk.R cannot be resolved SilkSpinnerAdapter.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/adapters   line 5  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkSpinnerAdapter.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/adapters   line 13 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkSpinnerAdapter.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/adapters   line 14 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkListFragment.java   /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/fragments/list line 118    Java Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android' dialog_layout.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 20 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingEnd' in package 'android' dialog_layout.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 29 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'   dialog_layout.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 20 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android' dialog_layout.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 62 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'   dialog_layout.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 62 Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 222    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 235    Java Problem
The import com.afollestad.silk.R cannot be resolved SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 13 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 310    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 311    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 289    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 306    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 323    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 342    Java Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingEnd' in package 'android' dialog_listitem_radio.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 8  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 317    Java Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingStart' in package 'android'   dialog_listitem_radio.xml   /Silk-master/res/layout line 8  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SilkDialog.java /Silk-master/src/com/afollestad/silk/dialogs    line 318    Java Problem
```

What I have done:
I unzipped the silk library and imported it into eclipse as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IYnkIre1sA).
Then I checked the isLibrary thing in properties.
I have been searching for an answer but I am unable to find one. I have tried cleaning the project and removing and re-importing. None of these worked. This library is perfect for what I want and I really want to get it to work. If you need any more information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using these below attributes and its supported from API level >17

```
    paddingStart
    paddingEnd
    layout_marginStart
    layout_marginEnd
```

your min sdk is less than API 17.

```
Added in API level 17
public static final int paddingStart
public static final int layout_marginStart
```